# What is a good usecase for Guice Mapbinder?

Tags: java, guice

I've seen it used, but I'm not sure the usage were good usecase examples. Do you have examples of **idiomatic** usages of [Guice Mapbinder](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/source/browse/extensions/multibindings/src/com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.java)? (Cases where Mapbinder is really the correct tool to solve a problem)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "good usage"?

Comment: @Simon - it's hard to define a good, elegant design. I'm looking for usecases that are not "code smell".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Offhand, it looks like a reasonable way to create a registry of runtime-named implementations of a common interface.  Consider selecting one of many plugins/modes/whatever from a command line or configuration file: the desired injection can't be known at compile time.  A MapBinder provides an easy runtime lookup without resorting to type-switching.

Answer (score 1):

I extensively use it in [Guts-GUI](http://kenai.com/projects/guts/pages/Home).
You can take a look, in particular, at the `ResourceModule`, where it is used to map the right `ResourceConverter<T>` for a given type `T`:

```
Map<TypeLiteral<?>>, ResourceConverter<?>>
```

The `MapBinder` is directly created in the `Resources` helper class.

This way, any module can add its own resource converters for its own types, e.g. `MessageModule` adds its own converters.

I also used it as `Map<Integer, WindowProcessor>>` in `WindowsModule` to define an ordered list of `WindowProcessor`s to be applied, one after another, to a newly created window..

Once again, this allows various modules to insert their own processor to the list applied to every window: `ResourceModule` uses it to add the ability of automatic injection of  i18n resources to windows.